# Are stainless steel saucepan glass lids dishwasher friendly?

Tags: equipment, cleaning

All in the title really...

Are stainless steel Saucepan glass lids dishwasher friendly?

Comment: Probably depends on the brand. You should refer to your manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 2):

The lids are most likely dishwasher safe.

Factors in *dishwasher safe* designation:

- Will the item be damaged by high temp water? (probably not, this is a pan)
- Will the item be damaged by the drying cycle heat elements? (probably not, it was designed to take high heat)
- Is the item susceptible to the corrosive detergents used in dish washing?

I think most better brands would pass all three factors.

The corrosion from the detergent is the wildcard. On a lesser quality brand of kitchen ware:

- Might the hardware (screw and washer) that attaches any handle knobs be a low quality metal?
- Might the glass be soft and susceptible to abrasion? Is it really glass?
- If a steel ring surrounds the lid edge, is it low quality metal?

I agree with comment: check with the manufacturer.

OT because we're talking lids here: but, most non-stick pans are not dishwasher safe. And of course: don't put your well seasoned iron cookware in a DW.

Comment: I've been putting non-stick pans in the dishwasher for 10 years.  That's not what kills them, though if the coating is scratched right through it will flake off in the dishwasher faster than washing by hand.

Comment: Then you have very high quality non-stick pans.

Comment: On the contrary, we've just bought some decent ones but some had survived since student days (though not in daily use) so were about as cheap as you can buy.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always specified, but plain glass is dishwasher safe, and the knob and its fastenings must be able to take steam.  That's not to say there won't be a bit of an issue - on some of ours there's a gap under the knob that fill with water in the dishwasher - and not necessarily clean water.  This is especially true if the screw needs tightening.  Ours always go through the dishwasher as we essentially have a policy of "it either is dishwasher safe or it wasn't" except for items with sentimental value.  Very little actually gets ruined.